# Como configurar o FuelPHP em ubuntu 16?

Tags: apache, virtualhost

Preciso "clonar" uma aplicação FuelPHP, que roda em Lamp (linux) no server da empresa.

**Tudo correu bem e suave** na primeira tentativa, que foi feita na máquina local do cliente. Já este roda em Xampp com Win 10.

**Mas agora que estou tentando rodar na minha maquina (Ubuntu 16), os problemas começaram**.

Toda a instalação é tranquila, e o Fuel PHP abre normalmente, mas quando vou abrir uma view (e um controller), ele diz que aquele arquivo não existe.

Eis a mensagem de erro quando acesso pelo navegador:

> URL = xxx.xxxx.xxxx/jikken/index/
>
> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /jiji/index/ was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at xxxx.xxxx.xxxxPort 80

Não sei se é erro na configuração do VirtualHost do apache ou no arquivo `.htaccess`.

Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

Comment: Já ativou o mod_rewrite? `sudo a2emod rewrite`

Comment: FUNCIONOU facim facim!!!   **obrigada** !!   Ja vou estudar o que eh isso de "rewrite" !!  (por favor coloque como resposta, para eu aceitar como sendo valida ! )

Comment: Postei, que bom que funcionou :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando você instala o Apache2 no Ubuntu, geralmente ele vem com o `mod_rewrite` desabilitado.

Nesse caso, você pode habilitá-lo assim:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Comment: @CamilaYamamoto tudo bem? eu não entendi seu comentário. O comando não é o mesmo da resposta?

Comment: @CamilaYamamoto mas a resposta estava com erro de digitação, não tem nada a ver com o comando ter mudado. Eu realmente vi que a resposta estava errada quando vi seu comentário. De fato o comando `a2enmod`, ao invés de `a2emod` (digitado errado). O comando não foi atualizado. Seu comentário me ajudou a perceber o erro de digitação.